# Alineamiento left y right dentro de td en xhtml2pdf y Django

Tags: html, django, xhtml2pdf

¿Como puedo alinear dos elementos dentro de un td en xhtml2pdf?
Quiero separar las el simbolo del monto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
así me gustaría que quedara
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

probé lo siguiente -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975247/align-two-spans-inside-a-td-one-left-and-one-right
pero no me funciona.

```
<table id="upp">
  <tr>
    <td class="prueba">
      <span>Left</span>
      <span>Right</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

css

```
.prueba {
    justify-content: space-between;
    color: #00dd1c;
}
```

Comment: Te recomendaría que colocaras tu código para que te pudiéramos responder de una mejor manera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una razón por la cual no me funciona es que xhtml2pdf no toma algunos estilos (xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html) Cambie a WeasyPrint y ahora si funciona.

La solución que explica @Julio Cesar si funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr un resultado algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tu CSS debería ser así:

```
.prueba {
    width: 100px;
    display: flex; /* Evidentemente debe tener "display: flex" para que la propiedad "justify-content" funcione */
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

---

```
<table id="upp">
 <tr>
   <td class="prueba">
     <span>$</span>
     <span>4.524</span>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Cabe recalcar, que el `<td>` (`.prueba`) debe tener una anchura, es decir que no se adapte a su contenido. También la distancia puede cambiar deacuerdo a la anchura, así que desde ahí, puedes ir modificando la distancia.

Por otra parte, si quieres que el texto este centrado y que el signo `$` este alejado, podrías hacer algo así:

```
.prueba {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;

}

.prueba span:first-child {
    margin-right: Xpx;
}
```

Como puedes ver, hay varias maneras de lograrlo. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias Julio Cesar.
Una razón por la cual no me funciona es que xhtml2pdf no toma algunos estilos (https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html)
Cambie a WeasyPrint y ahora si funciona (probaré la forma que indicas).